# Live Network Streaming in Windows Form Application

Tags: winforms

I am trying to pass `http://192.168.0.0:2000` as url for live streaming to AxWindowsMediaPlayer.
here `192.168.0.0` is the IP and `2000` is port of the machine on which I have started the live streaming.
When I pass this URL directly to Windows Media Player streaming works fine.
But when I pass it to AxWindowsMediaPlayer through my C# code streaming does not work.
I want streaming to occur through my code.

Thanks in advance.